# Segmentation fault on returning int

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault, binary-search

Below I have my two functions which are, when when insertItem calls findIndex producing a segmentation fault. For some reason this happens when the value is returned. (I will include the cout statements so that it is easy to see exactly where this error happens). I am trying to locate the index of a value which is not in the list so -1 should be returned but never does. The output is below.

```
template <class ItemType>
int SortedList<ItemType>::findIndex(ItemType item) {
  cout << "Entering findIndex function" << endl;
  int first = 0;
  int last = length-1;
  int middle;
  bool found = false;
  while(!found) {
    middle = (first+last)/2;
    cout << "In findIndex, this is middle: " << middle << " and this is     the item: " << item << " and this is the length: " << length << endl;
    if(info[middle] == item) {
      cout << "In findIndex found is now true" << endl;
      found = true;
    }
    else if(item < info[middle])
      last = middle-1;
    else// if(item > info[middle])                                                                                                                                                   
      first = middle+1;
    if(first > last)//else// if(first > last)                                                                                                                                        
      break;
  }
  cout << "About to exit and return value from findIndex function" << endl;

  if(found == true) {
    cout << "findIndex Function: the index of the found value was " <<     middle << endl;
    return middle;
  }
else {
    cout << "findindex Function: -1 was returned" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
}




template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::insertItem(ItemType item) {
  cout << "Inside insertItem function, length: " << length << endl;
  if(findIndex(item) != -1)
    cout << "**Item already in the list" << endl;
  else if(length == Max_Items)
    cout << "**There is no room in the list" << endl;
  else {
    cout << "before the try" << endl;
    try{
      cout << "This is length at the start of the insertItem function: " << length << endl;
      if(length == 0) {//if the list is empty item becomes the first item in the list                                                                                               \

        cout << "This is right after length==0 in insertItem function" << endl;
        info[0] = item;//was this->inf...                                                                                                                                            
        length++;
        cout << "This is length right after incrementing it up" << length << endl;
      }
      else {//its not the first item in the list                                                                                                                                     
        for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
          cout << "This is the length and i respectively right inside the for in insertItem" << length << " " << i << endl;
          if(i == length) {
            cout << "this is where i == length" << endl;
            info[i] = item;
            length++;
            break;
          }

          if(info[i] < item)
            continue;
          //inserting the item where it needs to go                                                                                                                                  
          for(int p = length; p > i; p--) {//was >=                                                                                                                                  
            info[p] = info[p-1];
          }
          //item = info[i];                                                                                                                                                          
          info[i] = item;
          length++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }catch(...) {cout << "**insertItem failed" << endl;}
  }
  cout << "This is length at the end of the insert item function: " <<     length << endl;
}
```

output:
...
Inside insertItem function, length: 0

Entering findIndex function

In findIndex, this is middle: 0 and this is the item: Name: Eman  ID: 81012 and this is the length: 0

About to exit and return value from findIndex function

findindex Function: -1 was returned

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

~$:

So even the print saying -1 was returned is hit but nothing ever gets back to the original function. I am not sure as to what could cause a seg fault in this area. Could this return do it?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Seriously, you're using templates and not able to debug your own code using your debugger?  That is a recipe for disaster.  Learn to use the debugger, as it is basically a requirement, given the advanced nature of what you're doing.

Comment: @Rabbid76 What do you mean by this? Sorry I am new to this sort of thing

Comment: @MichaelSmith `for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++)` -- Loops written with `<=` as the condition are always suspect of a buffer overrun if `i` is being used as an index into a 0-based container or buffer.  Why not `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following loop:

```
for(int p = length; p > i; p--) {
    info[p] = info[p-1];
```

probably writes to 1 index past the length of the array, because valid array indexes probably range from `0` to `length - 1`.

A write to an illegal memory location can corrupt the stack, and this is likely to manifest as a crash when returning from a function.

Still, you *really* need to start using a debugger.

Comment: I realize that and will from now on. This isn't where the seg fault takes place. The reason I posted this was of where the seg fault was taking place, I just wasnt able to debug where it was. it threw me off

Comment: @MichaelSmith *This isn't where the seg fault takes place.* -- But could be where the disaster begins.  Unlike most other computer languages, C++ doesn't pop up a message box as soon as you make mistakes like this.  That loop corrupts memory, and memory corruption leads to undefined behavior from there on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie its not possible in my case for this to happen because p must be greater than i meaning p is at least 1 and when p is at least 1 the lowest index which can be accessed is 0 (1-1=0)

Comment: Well, as the comments in the main thread stated, post a [mcve].  No one knows what the value of `i` is at that point, except on pure faith from what you're saying.